# JunitParamsRunner Test

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am trying to run the following code and i get a wrong number of arguments error.

```
package Homework7;
import static junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.$;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)

public class Problem3TestClass {
    private Problem3Class p3class;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Object[] Problem3TestClass(){
        return $(
//              Parameters are: (1, 2)
//              1 = x,2 = y             
//              Test case 1
                $(12223,1)


                );
    }
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        p3class = new Problem3Class();
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "Problem3TestClass")
    public void test(int[] x,int y)
    {
        assertEquals(y,p3class.countRepeated(x));
    }

}
```

My countRepeated method is invocated in the following way

```
public int countRepeated (int[] x)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment in [source](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/blob/master/src/main/java/junitparams/JUnitParamsRunner.java#L540)

`JUnitParamsRunner#$` method

> Should not be used to create var-args arrays, because of the way Java resolves
> var-args for objects and primitives.

So try to change the test method to accept `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`.
The following code should work.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Object[] Problem3TestClass() {
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int y = 2;
    return $(x, y);
}

@Test
@Parameters(method = "Problem3TestClass")
public void test(List<Integer> x, int y) {
    // update countRepeated to accept List<Integer> or do some conversion here
    assertEquals(y, p3class.countRepeated(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also recommend to change to List type. However, sometimes the implementations are not changed for test codes. To keep using int[], you can hold it as the last parameter.

```
public static final Object[] Problem3TestClass(){
    return $(
        $(12223, new int[] {12223}),
        $(6, new int[] {1,2,3})
    );
}
```

and the test case method:

```
@Test
@Parameters(method = "Problem3TestClass")
public void test(int y, int[] x)
{
    assertEquals(y, p3class.countRepeated(x));
}
```

Below is the sample of using List type as well.

```
public static final Object[] Problem3TestClass2(){
    return $(
        $(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), 6),
        $(Arrays.asList(1,-4), -3)
    );
}
```

Test case method:

```
@Test
@Parameters(method = "Problem3TestClass2")
public void test2(List<Integer> x, int y)
{
    assertEquals(y, p3class.countRepeated2(x));
}
```

Attached the two quick mock methods used in test.

```
class Problem3Class{
    public int countRepeated (int[] x){
        return Arrays.stream(x).sum();
    }
    public int countRepeated2 (List<Integer> x){
        return x.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+b);
    }
}
```